# Example of a function that is zero out a null measure set that is not continuous out of this set

Tags: analysis

Let $f : Q \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ a function that is $0$ outside of a set $ E \subset Q$ with measure of $E$ equals $0$. I mean, $E$ is a null measure set. ($Q$ a closed rectangle).

Then $f$ is continuous out of $E$?

Somebody told me that not necessarily, so I am looking for examples...

Thanks!

Comment: Take $E$ to be $\mathbb{Q}^n \cap Q$ and $f=1_E$, then $f$ is nowhere continuous because $E$ is dense in $Q$. Measure and topology don't play very nice with each other, even in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @zuggg The function should be zero outside of $E$, so your example doesn't satisfy the hypotheses.

Comment: @Ian You're right. But then $f$ restricted to $Q\backslash E$ is $0$, and is thus continuous on this set with respect to the topology induced by the metric, which is why I was asking exactly what is meant by "continuous out of $E$".

Comment: thank you, @Ian! It solved my problem. I do appreciate.